# How do I find the feed from an IP Camera

Tags: camera, network-programming, ip

Recently I purchased an IP camera (here's a link to the manual, in case that is needed: http://www.safehome.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/SafeHome_Manual-278040_278041-NORDIC.pdf ).

I would like to make a small Python program, where I can change and adjust different settings. Just so you will know in which way I'm heading, then I would like 4 IP cameras, where one of the feeds are shown in large and the other three are shown in small (standard surveillance-style). But the catch is, that is should be easy to adjust the delay for all the cameras, so the user can choose a number between 0 and 20 seconds, depending on how long they want the delay to be.

I've now connected my camera and I can use it, using the software from the manufacturer (viewed in a browser - which is not the best way). I assume that the first step is to find the feed from the camera - but I don't know how the images are transferred.

So my question is this:

- a) How does a (my) IP Camera send data to a (my) machine?
- b) In case that it is a feed/link - how do I find that, if it isn't in the manual?

If I go to the camera's IP-address in a browser, then it asks me to login, and then I just enter the camera's main menu. But I can see, that it has some kind of structure in there, because if I go to 'Settings', then it takes me to the URL: `10.0.0.34/web/admin.html`. So I imagined that the actual feed from the camera would be something along the lines of: `10.0.0.34/stream.mjpeg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use the Source!

1. **Navigate to the `admin.html` page** in your web browser
2. **Look for the `<img>` or `<video>` tag**, with a source that's something like what you mentioned (`10.0.0.34/steam.mjpeg`)
3. **Grab it in Python** and display it